# How do I use datetime class to filter out data within certain year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

```
  #Filter the data by displaying data with date >2018:
import datetime as dt

df2[df2['Year'] > dt.date(year > 2018)]
```

[image: the year column has a dtype of datetime64[ns]]

> I have checked the documentation and still cant find a way to filter the date to only display
> rows with year > 2018

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: If the datatype of 'Year' is just an integer, you could directly do `df2[df2['Year']] > 2018`

Comment: the data type of year is datetime64[ns] i have already tried the above and since its not an integer i have had no luck

Comment: Just curious how you create a datetime64 like year?

Comment: `df = = df[df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y') > '2018']`

Comment: i tried this with both single equal sign and double and it returns all false

Comment: Please provide entire or at least part of your dataframe. Mention me with @Drakax when you've updated your question or I won't receive notification ;)